# jQuery .focusOut() conditional action dependent on next selected element

Tags: jquery

I have a table cell with a text input `#usernameInput` and a link `#saveLink`. Using jQuery I have a function assigned to the  click event of the `#saveLink`.

What I'm trying to acheive is, When the `#usernameInput` loses focus I want to hide it. Unless it loses focus to the `#saveLink`.
In other words, if the user click anywhere other than the `#saveLink` I want to hide the `#usernameInput` otherwise call the click event on the `#saveLink`.

I have no problem handleing the `$('#usernameInput').focusout()` but I cant get it to detect if the save link was clicked.

Here is what i have so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#usernameInput').focusout(function ()
{

    if (!$('#saveLink').is(':focus'))
    {
        $('#usernameInput').hide();
    }
    return;

});</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I'm trying to acheive is, When
>   the '#usernameInput' loses focus I
>   want to hide it. Unless it loses focus
>   to the '#saveLink'. In other words, if
>   the user click anywhere other than the
>   '#saveLink' I want to hide the
>   '#usernameInput' otherwise call the
>   click event on the '#saveLink'.

Maybe you could bind an event to the body and just check the `e.target`

```
$("body").click(function(event){
  if(!$(event.target).is("#saveLink")){
    $("#usernameInput").hide();
  }
});
```

***disclaimer*** this is just pseudo code for now... update in a bit.

Comment: This works great, but what about when the focus is lost by tab?

Comment: Its not perffect. Focus is not always related to click event (example tab like Owain mention). I prefer Potter's answer (which was down vote for unknown reason) since its works also with tab too.

Comment: Ok it seems has its own downside too (check comment in Potter's answer)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is new, but I found found a better way today (3.5 years later): **event.relatedTarget** is the element you actually clicked.

```
$elementLosingFocus.focusout(function (event) {
    var $elementYouAreTesting;

    $elementYouAreTesting = $("#whatever");

    if (elementYouAreTesting[0] === event.relatedTarget) {
        // you clicked the element you were testing!
    } else {
        // you clicked something else
    }
});
```

Comment: This is propapbly the "right way" do the thing but sadly its not currently working with Firefox
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout

Comment: It's not populated in my use case, I'm using Chrome